# Is there a live linux distribution with a specific set of softwares

Tags: live-usb, livecd, libreoffice

How do I find a live linux distribution with a contain at least a specific set of software that I want?

If you might be wondering, I am trying to find a live linux distribution (can be live dvd or live cd or live usb) that contains veracrypt and libreoffice that is out of the box (without the need to install).

Comment: While many distributions come with LibreOffice pre-installed, VeraCrypt is a somewhat more specific requirement and I am unsure if any of the wide-spread distributions come with it pre-installed. If you want to distribute such a distribution in your company or among friends and family, it is easy to build your own custom distribution from existing distributions with these two packages installed. Take a look at this article for example: https://www.linuxvoice.com/build-your-own-linux-distro/

Answer (score 1):

You can view all distro GNU/Linux on **http://www.distrowatch.com/**.

Currently, I am usingGnu/Linux Fedora 25, which can be installed from a Live CD.

It has Libreoffice pre-installed, but you have to install veracrypt from this site **https://fedora.pkgs.org/25/rpm-sphere/veracrypt-1.19-3.2.x86_64.rpm.html**

Comment: Hi Riccardo, in my question I mention without the need to install. Veracrypt should run just like Libreoffice.

Comment: See the link at http://www.distrowatch.com, you will find many distributions

Answer (score 1):

You can always build your own LiveDVD - This is the instruction set that I've used before and it works well

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Answer (score 1):

The RescueZilla team is planning for incorporating VeraCrypt into a upcoming version of the RescueZilla Live-DVD (Live-system). ref1: [SourgeForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/rescuezilla/discussion/support/thread/b46a63cc3b/), ref2: [Github](https://github.com/rescuezilla/rescuezilla/issues/2).